# Accessing a deployed website on IIS on a different machine on the network

Tags: asp.net, iis

I just deployed a website on IIS. After clicking on the browse button. The following url opened up

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

On IIS Manager this is what it looks like

```
Sites
|
|_Kites
   |_aspnet_client
   |_bin
   |_...
```

My question is how do I access this website on a different computer now that it has been deployed on IIS
I tried this url.

```
http://10.xxx.xx.51:8080/
```

However when I try this url  I get the error site cannot be reached.
Any suggestions on why this might be happening ?

This is what my bindings look like

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you set Edit binding option in IIS server ? if not then do this.

You have to go to Edit binding option in IIS server and Add Site binding. their you have to choose your ip address and port as well.

Now you have to go to Windows Administrative tools and go to Windows firewall and advanced options then this window opens

[image]

Now go to Inbound Rules on the left corner then this window opens

[image]

Now click on New rule now this window opens

[image]

Now choose port and click next then this window opens

[image]

Now specify the same port as you have set on edit binding in IIS and click next then
[image]

Now, no need to change and option on this page and next page also just click next and then
[image]

Now enter the name of the rule and description and click finish...Its done.
You can access it on different computer...
Hope, this will help you.
If you find it helpful please mark my answer....Thanks

Comment: Now you have to go to Windows Administrative tools and go to Windows firewall and advanced options

Comment: i dont think this is a firewall issue now

Comment: I have answered it you just try that and let me know....thanks

Comment: yep i just needed to put 8080 as an exemption

Answer (score 0):

You can try line below on cmd:

```bash
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Hosting Local Website On LAN" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=8080
```